# GAE initial login

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Profile model that I use to store data about users.

This includes their username for another website so that I can use the website API to grab information about boardgames they own.

I'm running into an issue if the user logs in and immediately creates an event I get an error because their username for the API has not been entered.

So I have a few ways I can handle this and I'm wondering which is best:

1. Can just handle this error in my code (which I'll probably do anyways) and if it is empty set an error asking them to complete that information in their profile.
2. Whenever a user logs in for the first time direct them to the profile page and ask them to complete the username field.

I should do both but I'm confused on the best way to do this...

(First time asking on StackOverflow so unsure of what info is needed)

Comment: *if the user logs in and immediately creates an event I get an error* - shouldn't a username have been assigned if the user is "logging in"? Shouldn't that be part of the login process?

Comment: @MattDMo the username is from another service. Do both. Start with the second and add extra the error handling.

Comment: I'm just unsure on how to do the second.... I don't know how to detect if it is their first/subsequent login

Comment: set a variable `not_first_time = True` associated with the user after they complete the login/registration process. Then, add logic `if not_first_time: pass; else: do_first_time_stuff()`

Comment: So I'm using the boilerplate. The boilerplate has a builtin BaseHandler that all handlers inherit from. 

I decided to add logic to the base handler render method that checks if the required information in the profile is there. If it isn't it redirects to the profile page and displays the error asking them to complete the information. Which is causing an infinite loop now...